# p:messages with autoUpdate disappearsafter value change listener triggered

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, valuechangelistener

We have global p:messages defined in tempate with autoUpdate set to true.
This is the place where we are shwoing all the messages from included content.

On one of the pages we have panel with save button. User fill in some fields and  after succesfull save we need to:
1. Display succes message
2. Fill in automaticly other fields on same page based on saved data

So in the bean we are adding FacesMessage , set data based on saved object and rerender those other fields.
Unfotunatly those fields have some value change listeners attachted to them. So we end up with two ajax requests. First from the save button and second from the value change listnerer defined on one of the auto filled fields. The result is that succes message appear for short amount of time (it dissapear after second ajax). How can we keep this message after second ajax without setting auto update on messages to false?

Thanks for any adivce.

P.S. We are using primefaces 3 so ignore autoUpdates is not an option :(

Comment: if ignoreAutoUpdate on components is not an option, remove the autoUpdate from the `p:messages`....

Comment: Then I would have to go through all of the pages in the project and ensure to rerender p:messages on every action, linster etc. Disabling autoUpdate is not an option either

Comment: One workaround is to add another messages for this specific panel (or generally for those scenarios with multiple ajaxes) with autoupdate set to false and manage rerendering it manually .

Comment: But then you have '2' messages at a certain moment...

Comment: Those specific cases are excluded from main messages. But still we have to manually rerender  new messages to make it disappear at some point. Because of it we are still searching for better solution